# How do I obtain an element from a dataframe only if there's a corresponding element in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
first_df['Abbrev'] = ['HW', 'GB', 'TT']
first_df['Val'] = ['Hello World', 'Good Bye', '']

second_df['Value'] = ['Hello World', 'Good Bye', 'Good Bye']
```

and my expected output is:

```
output_df['result'] = ['HW', 'GB', 'GB']
```

I've tried using:

```
output_df['result'] = first_df[first_df.Val.isin(second_df.Value)]
if first_df['Abbrev']:
    return output_df['result']
```

which doesn't produce desirable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map`

```
second_df['Value'].map(dict(zip(first_df['Val'],first_df['Abbrev'])))
```

Comment: Although when I do this, the order of the output is not preserved due to the properties of the dictionary. Is there a way to preserve the order? I tried `collections.OrderedDict` which didn't work

Comment: @excelsior the output's order is determined by the second_df['Value'] not the map dict

Comment: @excelsior is second_df['Value'] change every time ?

Comment: Sorry, the problem occured in a previous preprocessing step and isn't related to this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing an inner merge between the two frames on the 'Val' and 'Value' columns.  Then from the result, drop the unwanted columns ('Val' and 'Value'). `output=pd.merge(first_df,second_df,left_on='Val',right_on='Value').drop(['Val','Value'],axis=1)`